# How to tell when a text field is empty in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to add an event listener that listens for whenever the text field goes blank (IE all text is deleted). Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
txtField.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,onChange);

function onChange(e:Event)
{
    if(e.currentTarget.length==0)
    {
        trace("empty")
    }
}
```

Comment: @Allan are you sure it works on Event.CHANGE. I guess this will work with TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT.

Comment: @Allan. I actually tried and found that, this won't work if it is Multiline TextField. It must be SingleLine. Thanks.

Comment: @RajneeshGaikwad Working for for me even with multiline? This is assuming you are using the classic textfield.